# how to build Sequence-to-sequence autoencoder in keras with embedding layer?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

I want to build a  Sequence-to-sequence autoencoder in keras. The purpose is to "doc2vec".

In the documents on keras blog, I found an example: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

What if I need to add an embedding layer to this? If we are dealing with a paragraph of text, we suppose should firstly tokenize the text, embedding it with pre-trained vector, right?

Do I need a Dense or time distributed dense layer in decoder?  Do I need to reverse the order of the sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The embedding layer should be the first layer. In my opinion it does not have to be pretrained. As for the dense decoding layer: People prefer autoencoder with similiar encoding/decoding architecture, but this is not a must. I think the best approach would be to just try it out and get a feeling what works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedding layer *can only be used as the first layer in a model* as the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) states, so something like this:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
embedded = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, ...))(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(embedded)
```

**We should firstly tokenize the text, embedding it with pre-trained vector, right?** Yes, this is the default option. You *only train your own embeddings if you have a sufficiently large enough corpus* otherwise [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) are often used. There is a [Keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py) that uses GloVe and the internal `Tokenizer` to pass text into a model with Embedding layer.

For decoding, you will need a `Dense` layer but using `TimeDistributed` is optional with version 2. By default `Dense` will apply the kernel to every timestep of your 3D tensor you pass:

```
decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoded)
# (batch_size, timesteps, vocab_size)
```

It's worth noting that taking the top N most frequent words will speed up training, otherwise that `softmax` will become very costly to compute. The Keras example also takes a limited number of words and every other word is mapped to a special UNKnown token.

Comment: For autoencoder, suppose x=y. if use embedding layer, my inputs are tokenized one-hot number, while be embedded in the model, then go through 2 layers of RNN,  then compare with the label which is the inputs (tokenized number). it seems the model is very hard to train.  Lost very high and accuracy very low, can't learn anything.  not sure where I get it wrong